# how to properly make a reusable component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I make reusable component like this:

```
export type ElementKeysType =
  | keyof ViewStyle
  | keyof TextStyle
  | keyof ImageStyle;

export const handleElementProps = <T>(obj: T, keys: ElementKeysType[]) => {
  const stylesProps = Object.fromEntries(
    keys.filter(key => key in obj).map(key => [key, obj[key as keyof T]]),
  );
  const elementProps = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(obj)
      .filter(key => !keys.includes(key as ElementKeysType))
      .map(key => [key, obj[key as keyof T]]),
  );

  const elementStyles = createStyle(stylesProps);

  return [elementStyles, elementProps];
};

const createStyle = (styles: ViewStyle | ImageStyle | TextStyle) =>
  StyleSheet.create({
    element: styles,
  });


const createWithStylePropsComponent =
  <P extends object>(
    Component: React.ComponentClass<P, any> | React.FunctionComponent<P>,
  ): React.FunctionComponent<P> =>
  ({ style, ...props }: P & { style?: StyleProp<ElementKeysType> }) => {
    // find style keys from props
    const [elementStyles, elementNativeProps] = handleElementProps(props, [
      ...RNViewStyleKeys,
      ...RNTextStyleKeys,
      ...RNImageStylekeys,
    ]);
    return (
      <Component
        {...(elementNativeProps as P)}
        // make component receive style prop
        style={[elementStyles.element, style]}
      />
    );
  };

export const DynamicView = createWithStylePropsComponent<
  ViewProps & ViewProps['style']
>(View);

export const DynamicText = createWithStylePropsComponent<
  TextProps & TextProps['style']
>(Text);

export const DynamicTouchableOpacity = createWithStylePropsComponent<
  TouchableOpacityProps & TouchableOpacityProps['style']
>(TouchableOpacity);

export const DynamicImage = createWithStylePropsComponent<
  ImageProps & ImageProps['style']
>(Image);

export const DynamicPressable = createWithStylePropsComponent<
  PressableProps['style'] & PressableProps
>(Pressable);
```

when i use it, it's like this:

```
 <DynamicTouchableOpacity
      flexDirection="row"
      alignItems="center"
      justifyContent="space-between"
      paddingLeft={Pixel(24)}
      paddingVertical={Pixel(24)}
      onPress={onPress}>
      <View>
        <DynamicText
          color={appTheme.typographyHighEmphasis}
          fontSize={Pixel(15)}
          lineHeight={Pixel(24)}
          letterSpacing={Pixel(0.75)}
          fontFamily={fonts.poppinsMedium}>
          {displayDate}
        </DynamicText>
        <DynamicText
          color={appTheme.typographyLowEmphasis}
          fontSize={Pixel(13)}
          lineHeight={Pixel(22)}
          letterSpacing={Pixel(0.25)}
          fontFamily={fonts.poppinsRegular}>
          {remarks}
        </DynamicText>
      </View>
      <DynamicView
        alignItems="center"
        flexDirection="row"
        paddingRight={Pixel(8)}>
        <DynamicView marginRight={Pixel(12)}>
          <DynamicText
            fontSize={Pixel(11)}
            lineHeight={Pixel(16)}
            letterSpacing={Pixel(0.25)}
            fontFamily={fonts.poppinsMedium}
            textAlign="right"
            style={[
              {
                color: isDebitTransaction
                  ? appTheme.typographyPrimary
                  : appTheme.typographyAccent,
              },
            ]}>
            {label}
          </DynamicText>
          <DynamicText
            textAlign="right"
            fontSize={Pixel(13)}
            lineHeight={Pixel(22)}
            letterSpacing={Pixel(0.25)}
            fontFamily={fonts.poppinsSemiBold}
            style={[
              {
                color: isDebitTransaction
                  ? appTheme.typographyPrimary
                  : appTheme.typographyAccent,
              },
            ]}>
            {amount}
          </DynamicText>
          {isDebitTransaction && (
            <DynamicText
              color={appTheme.typographyLowEmphasis}
              fontSize={Pixel(11)}
              lineHeight={Pixel(16)}
              letterSpacing={Pixel(0.25)}
              fontFamily={fonts.poppinsMedium}>
              {`Due ${dueDate}`}
            </DynamicText>
          )}
        </DynamicView>
        <Icon
          name="keyboard-arrow-right"
          size={Pixel(24)}
          color={appTheme.typographyLowEmphasis}
        />
      </DynamicView>
    </DynamicTouchableOpacity>
```

what i like about it is that with typescript auto suggestion, i save time styling and it's easy to distinguish style props rather than think of another property on StyleSheet as the app gets big and native props for component is auto suggested.

But does doing this slows the app? i mean, every component goes on reusable hook createWithStylePropsComponent. But my idea is like this and maybe want to know suggestions how to improve it?

btw, these are the styles keys extracted from typescript:

```
import {
  FlexStyle,
  ImageStyle,
  ShadowStyleIOS,
  TextStyle,
  TextStyleAndroid,
  TextStyleIOS,
  ViewStyle,
} from 'react-native';

// keys extracted on react native typescript definitions

const flexStyleKeys = [
  'alignContent',
  'alignItems',
  'alignSelf',
  'aspectRatio',
  'borderEndWidth',
  'borderStartWidth',
  'bottom',
  'display',
  'end',
  'flex',
  'flexBasis',
  'flexDirection',
  'flexGrow',
  'flexShrink',
  'flexWrap',
  'height',
  'justifyContent',
  'left',
  'margin',
  'marginBottom',
  'marginEnd',
  'marginHorizontal',
  'marginLeft',
  'marginRight',
  'marginStart',
  'marginTop',
  'marginVertical',
  'maxHeight',
  'maxWidth',
  'minHeight',
  'minWidth',
  'overflow',
  'padding',
  'paddingBottom',
  'paddingEnd',
  'paddingHorizontal',
  'paddingLeft',
  'paddingRight',
  'paddingStart',
  'paddingTop',
  'paddingVertical',
  'position',
  'right',
  'start',
  'top',
  'width',
  'zIndex',
  'direction',
] as (keyof FlexStyle)[];

const shadowStyleIosKeys = [
  'shadowColor',
  'shadowOffset',
  'shadowOpacity',
  'shadowRadius',
] as (keyof ShadowStyleIOS)[];

const textStyleKeys = [
  'color',
  'fontFamily',
  'fontSize',
  'fontStyle',
  'fontWeight',
  'letterSpacing',
  'lineHeight',
  'textAlign',
  'textDecorationLine',
  'textDecorationStyle',
  'textDecorationColor',
  'textShadowColor',
  'textShadowOffset',
  'textShadowRadius',
  'textTransform',
  'testID',
] as (keyof TextStyle)[];

const textStyleIosKeys = [
  'fontVariant',
  'letterSpacing',
  'textDecorationColor',
  'textDecorationStyle',
  'writingDirection',
] as (keyof TextStyleIOS)[];

const textStyleAndroidkeys = [
  'textAlignVertical',
  'includeFontPadding',
] as (keyof TextStyleAndroid)[];

const viewStyleKeys = [
  'backfaceVisibility',
  'backgroundColor',
  'borderBottomColor',
  'borderBottomEndRadius',
  'borderBottomLeftRadius',
  'borderBottomRightRadius',
  'borderBottomStartRadius',
  'borderBottomWidth',
  'borderColor',
  'borderEndColor',
  'borderLeftColor',
  'borderLeftWidth',
  'borderRadius',
  'borderRightColor',
  'borderRightWidth',
  'borderStartColor',
  'borderStyle',
  'borderTopColor',
  'borderTopEndRadius',
  'borderTopLeftRadius',
  'borderTopRightRadius',
  'borderTopStartRadius',
  'borderTopWidth',
  'borderWidth',
  'opacity',
  'testID',
  'elevation',
] as (keyof ViewStyle)[];

export const RNViewStyleKeys = [
  ...viewStyleKeys,
  ...flexStyleKeys,
  ...shadowStyleIosKeys,
  'transform',
] as (keyof ViewStyle)[];

export const RNTextStyleKeys = [
  ...textStyleKeys,
  ...textStyleIosKeys,
  ...textStyleAndroidkeys,
  ...RNViewStyleKeys,
] as (keyof TextStyle)[];

const imageStyleKeys = [
  'resizeMode',
  'backfaceVisibility',
  'borderBottomLeftRadius',
  'borderBottomRightRadius',
  'backgroundColor',
  'borderColor',
  'borderWidth',
  'borderRadius',
  'borderTopLeftRadius',
  'borderTopRightRadius',
  'overflow',
  'overlayColor',
  'tintColor',
  'opacity',
] as (keyof ImageStyle)[];

export const RNImageStylekeys = [
  ...imageStyleKeys,
  ...flexStyleKeys,
  ...shadowStyleIosKeys,
  'transform',
] as (keyof ImageStyle)[];
```

Comment: @JojoNarte yes, good point, but i have been digging in to this kind of approach/idea and i saw it's quiet popular, though i don't think i would use this approach in my question now, the idea, it is used in eigen, open source(3k stars) 
https://github.com/artsy/eigen/blob/5225c110895f85532ebf1d5940c4a1b0901b062e/src/palette/elements/Box/Box.tsx

and here: https://github.com/Shopify/restyle

the idea of styles as props is quiet good though, i'd pick Shopify/restyle if i have to start from scratch, no need to think of stylesheet props as app gets big

Comment: as for shopify/restyle approach, here it is, https://github.com/Shopify/restyle#defining-your-theme and styled system, https://styled-system.com/variants/

and to read more about both is here: https://whoisryosuke.com/blog/2020/restyle-for-react-native-vs-styled-system/